# UISlider with tag how to call?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, tags, uislider

I am trying to access or call an uislider based on the set tag.

for an example lets say i have a uislider named slider and i have given this slider a int tag of 1.

```
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider.......]];
slider.tag = 1;
```

how then would i access this slider object based on the tag value.

```
        [self updateSlider: [slider viewWithTag:1]];
```

will give me the following error

"Incompatible pointer types sending 'UIView *' to parameter of type 'UISlider *"

so my question is.

how would one call this objects based on the tag value? is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can access the slider if u added it to view for example

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc]...];
  slider.tag = 100;//setting the tag (set tag to some different higher numbers) 
  [self.view addSubview:slider];//added it to view
}
```

some where u are using the slider, but u want to access it with tag (as u said in your question) u can do it like below

```
UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)[self.view viewWithTag:100]; //get the slider
[self updateSlider: slider];//call to update slider
```

Comment: Thanks Shan, I didn't realise that tags where accessed view their containing view... makes perfect sense and dis the job